# how to Download file over https python requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to download a file over https using python requests. I wrote a sample code for this. When i run my code it doesnot download the pdf file given in link. Instead downloads the html code for the login page. I checked the response status code and it is giving 200. To download the file login is necessary. How to download the file?

My code:

```
import requests
import json

# Original File url = "https://seller.flipkart.com/order_management/manifest.pdf?sellerId=8k5wk7b2qk83iff7"

url = "https://seller.flipkart.com/order_management/manifest.pdf"
uname = "xxx@gmail.com"
pwd = "xxx"
pl1 = {'sellerId':'8k5wk7b2qk83i'}
payload = {uname:pwd}
ses = requests.Session()
res = ses.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload))
resp = ses.get(url, params = pl1)
print resp.status_code
print resp.content
```

I tried several solutions including Sending a `POST` request with my login creadentials using requests' session object then downloading file using same session object. but it didn't worked.
EDIT:
It still is returning the html for login page.

Comment: It seems you cannot download it with single request. First you need to log in on the website. Than lookup cookie and pass it to requests.

Comment: I'd recommend to download it manually with Chrome. Just open Developer Tools, see Cookie request header and than just hard-code it.

Comment: I would look into `requests.Session` object, this will ensure cookies are passed back to the server.

Comment: @achampion I edited my code: Can you look at it?

Comment: HTML input field for login has name ```username```, not userid. You should read about HTML forms and how to work with them, but it is better to ask for REST access since HTML may change and break your code

Comment: This part does not have rest access.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried to pass the auth param to the GET? something like this:

```
resp = requests.get(url, params=pl1, auth=(uname, pwd))
```

And you can write `resp.content` to a local file myfile.pdf

```
fd = open('myfile.pdf', 'wb')
fd.write(resp.content)
fd.close()
```